# How to make Push Notification in Asp.Net Web App with Angular?

Tags: asp.net, angular, web-applications, notifications

I need to make Push Notification for every user, when product's price is changed.

Just like this:
[image]

The thing is that I have a job, that runs in the background and checks all the prices and sends emails to everyone informing on changes. I want to add these desktop notifications, so javascript and html5 doesn't work for me. Is there any library for .net that implements this functionality, or does anyone know any links to tutorials that I could read and use them??

Comment: there are 2 ways. You can have a web app and push notifications from chrome. The user will have to accept the request. Other thing is that you develop a native app for windows and confdigure push notifications using services like Azure notification hub

Comment: @It'satrap the first way works only on chrome or on other browsers too?

Comment: It will work on some other browsers as well. you can find the complete list here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification. But this way the user has to accept the notifications popup. Then only you will be able to push notifications to him

Comment: @It'satrap I need the accept notification. But as I can see I have to write javascript, to implement this. And I need to do this in C#

Comment: then developing a native app is the only option for you.

Comment: Why do you think you "need to do this in C#"? You're writing a web application. You shouldn't have an issue if some JavaScript is necessary.

Comment: @mason As I've mentioned. I have a background job in the server, that checks prices every n minutes. If found, then it should send notifications to every user. At this point I don't know how to call javascript from server... And I don't think that calling javascript functions from backend is appropriate...

Comment: It can certainly be appropriate. Some modern browsers such as Chrome support push notifications, with the push happening from the server side. You should really [check it out](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/) before blindly dismissing it by saying "I need to do this in C#". Some popular websites such as Facebook utilize these API's.

Comment: @mason do you have an asp.net mvc with angular example of making push notifications?

Comment: No, and Stack Overflow isn't here to hunt down examples for you. Read through their documentation. Then build a simple notification system, you don't even need to use Angular. And slowly build it up until you understand enough to actually integrate it into your application.